# polynomial regression in python from scratch

Tags: python, regression

I was doing this polynomial regression:

```py
for i in np.arange(1, len(coeff)):
    line += coeff[i] * x_pts ** i
```

I am aware of the concept but I don't understand why they are doing this step, can somebody explain, please.

Comment: what polynomial regression were you doing? Who is doing this step?

Comment: Please post the source code as text in your question.

Comment: https://github.com/pickus91/Polynomial-Regression-From-Scratch/blob/master/polynomial_regression.py .    This is what i was looking at. sorry guys if i am not very good at asking questions. Because this is my first question. But thank you that are very much interested in answering the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is just saying

```
y=a_n*x^n + a_(n-1)*x^(n-1) +...+ a_1*x^(1)
```

Although I'm not sure why exponent = 0 is not included.

Edit: OP should have included more code (and as text in the body of the question, not as an image).
Anyway, the original code is:

```py
line = coeff[0]
for i in np.arange(1, len(coeff)):
    line += coeff[i] * x_pts ** i
```

so we can see line is initialized as coeff[0], which is actually a constant not a coefficient.

Comment: I would appreciate an accepted answer if this helped, I need the points